# how to remove table option from ckeditor

Tags: java, ckeditor

I need help to remove the table icon from ckeditor. can anyone help me with it . I have to remove it as we dont need this functionality. I have already tried using various codes available in stackoverflow but nothing seems to work

Comment: You can remove it with CSS

Comment: Should this be JavaScript rather than Java?

Answer (score 1):

i saw in http://ckeditor.com/demo#toolbar.

Easy to config 3 function standard .

> 1.) Simple Toolbar 
>   2.) Standard Toolbar
>   3.) Full Toolbar

or u can remove code out.

Example want to remove Italic button 
go to remove code

```
<a id="id="cke_844" >
```